Are Indian research institutions more lenient about research misconduct than in other countries?
I read on theprint.in (mirror):

In any other country plagiarism and getting banned from publishing in an international journal would be treated as a research crime. The scientist would be suspended and an inquiry would be called,” a senior scientist at Presidency University said. “It’s only here that tainted scientists get promotions and rewards.”
[...]
Such allegations are serious, but most of these Indian scientists continue to thrive in their academic careers without facing consequences—a grim reflection of the state of India’s research ecosystem.

Are Indian research institutions more lenient about research misconduct than in other countries? If so, what would be the reason(s)?

The same article mentions:

Many of these scientists run in close quarters with their institutes’ administration, so it becomes convenient to turn a blind eye to such wrongdoings.

But that's true in most, if not all, countries.

Actually, it’s just not true. On Retraction Watch you can find multiple stories per day of this happening, in every country around the world, with no punishment. Everybody thinks their problems are unique.

@knzhou I think you have an answer. Write it up! :)

@knzhou I second Richard's comment, you're very welcome to write an answer.
